# Use of undeclared identifier - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I first created a property in my SecondViewController.h file using

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

And then synthesised it in the corresponding .m file using

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

I then created a function to create a webpage using a string which the user would cast as an argument. The function:

```
void createWebpage(NSString *webString) {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webString];
NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
}
```

And where it is called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

createWebpage(@"http://www.google.com");

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

However, in the last line of the function, `[webView loadRequest:requestUrl];`, webView produces the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'webView'. Why is this, and how can I fix it? All help appreciated.

Comment: wait for downvotes... You are not familiar with VERY basics - properties, instance methods and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a property which is a available in an object. But you are declaring a simple C method:

```
void createWebpage(NSString *webString) {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webString];
NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
}
```

This method will be executed in a "global context" but not on the object. So you can't access the objects properties.

Instead use a method:

```
- (void) createWebpage:(NSString *)webString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webString];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
}
```

And you have to use `self` to refer to the current object when you're accessing a property.

You can then call this method:

```
[self createWebpage:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

I really recommend you to read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @Isaac'Criterion'Akalanne I'm glad I could help you. Maybe you want to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`void createWebpage` is not a instance method, so the instance variables (such as `webView`) won't be accessible from there.
You must declare the method as: `-(void)createWebpage:(NSString *)webString`, and call it as `[self createWebPage:@"http://www.google.com"];`